# How rewrite .htaccess file conditions for laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Please help. I want mine apache web server will load mine project without `public folder` which has the `index.php` file.

How to rewrite the current URL 'http://localhost/couponsystem/public/'

for ''http://localhost/couponsystem/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**And do these steps as:**

- Rename `server.php` in your Laravel root folder to `index.php`
- Copy the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root
  folder.

[Reference](https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess)